# How do I deal with Glassfish included libs crashing with application supplied libs?

Tags: jackson, glassfish, jax-rs, cxf

A CXF JAX-RS application I have uses jackson to marshal POJOs to JSON. This works for the most part, but the other day it failed with a NPE when marshalling a deeply nested object.

After some investigation I found out that Jackson was included in Glassfish 3 (through Jersey) and after removing `jackson-core-asl.jar, jackson-jaxrs.jar, jackson-mapper-asl.jar` and `jackson-xc.jar` everything worked beautifully. I guess that Jackson 1.7.1 (included in GF3) had some bug that was fixed in the version shipped with my application (1.8).

Now the question is, why did I even have to do this in the first place? I would have thought libraries that are included in my war files should take presedence over any libraries in Glassfish's `/modules` directory.

Is there a cleaner way to do this than removing jars from the app server? Maybe there are other applications that depend on these jars ...

*On a side note, the problem still exists with our GF2 container, but I cannot find any jackson libraries in the `/lib` folder (there is no `/modules` folder like in GF3). Any clues on where Jackson might be hiding in GF2 (if at all)?*

Comment: Hi, Can you please share how you configured jackson in glassfish 3? I am trying to use jackson instead of jettison, with no success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Configured? I am not quite sure what you mean. There is no configuration. Just drop the shared libraries you need in the /lib folder. 

If you build your programs with maven then in the dependencies section you should have something like:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>YourVersion</version>
  <scope>provided</scope> <!-- provided says the the container (Glassfish) will provide it, instead of packing it in your war -->

Comment: Glassfish 3.1 comes with jettison and jackson; jettison is picked by default. I wonder how you configure it to work with jackson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell the Webapp classloader to prefer JARs provided by your WAR.

Add in your WEB-INF/sun-web.xml (or WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml):

```
...
<class-loader delegate="false"/>
...
```

See http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/glassfish.html#d4e1927

Answer (score 1):

consider using :
    `asadmin deploy --libraries ...`

Ref: http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/more_with_deploy_libraries

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is included by Jersey and Hadoop, if you might be running Jersey or interact with Hadoop system; and versions included are often old. So this could be one source for "ancient Jackson" problems.

Comment: I am aware of that, but why should that affect me? I do not use Jersey (I use CXF JAX-RS) or Hadoop. I am a bit unsure what part of the question you are answering :)

Comment: Just suggesting that if you were running Jersey on glassfish; or service itself was interacting with hadoop (which requires their heavyweight client), this might be a vector for old Jackson versions. Ruling out possibilities since these are common problems I've heard about. But sounds like not applicable to your case.