# Cannot run simple servlet on GlassFish-4

Tags: maven, jersey, servlet-3.0, glassfish-4

My simple REST based webservice does encounter a problem when I try do run it. It seems that the deployment succeeds, but when I access the servlet I get this error:

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[MySimpleServer]: Servlet.service() for servlet MySimpleServer threw exception
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

My root pom.xml is very simple and just contains these dependencies and plugins:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MySimpleServer</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MySimpleServer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MySimpleServer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Actually, it worked earlier today and I have not made any changes at all to the pom.xml file. Is it something with Glassfish4 server? I have made a clean build, redeployed the servlet, restarted GlassFish etc. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem when I've accidentally mixed `Jersey` / `JAX-RS` versions - IE having both Jersey 1 & 2 libs on the `classpath`.

I can't see how this happens with just the three dependencies in your `pom`, but I'm quite sure this is happening somewhere.

Looking at your `stacktrace`, I can see this is what's happening.

This is `javax.ws.rs-api/2.0` `UriBuilder.java`

```
118   public static UriBuilder fromUri(String uriTemplate) {
119        return newInstance().uri(uriTemplate);
120   }
```

Which is exactly what you're getting - a call to `UriBuilder.uri(String)` on `line 119`.

Looking at the equivalent line numbers in the `UriBuilder` source from `Jersey 1.8` and it's a `Javadoc` comment for a different method.

So, you've somehow got jax-rs 2 on your classpath and it's causing this problem.

Maybe you have it on a shared / common classloader, or a stray lib lying around.

**UPDATE**

Yes - glassfish ships with Jersey / JAX-RS libs. 
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759633/how-do-i-deal-with-glassfish-included-libs-crashing-with-application-supplied-li)

As an aside - if you're able, I'd upgrade to Jersey 2. 
Hope this helps

Will

Comment: Thanks! I am using GlassFish 4. Is it possible that GlassFish contains the other libs?

Comment: Yes it does (search for *.jar in the Glassfish directory). I would guess if you followed the instructions in the accepted answer of the SO question I linked above your problem will go away.

Comment: Actually I got it working. I don´t know what the problem was, but after each deploy I had to remove the whole GlassFish folder and setup a fresh install to get it to work with a new deployment. I will abandon GlassFish for Jetty. :-)