# Jackson with JodaTime and Jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I have a REST web-service created in Java. I am using [Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for the date and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for the JSON formatting. Everything is uploaded on a Glassfish 4.1 server

## Versions

- avax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
- joda-time-2.7.jar
- jackson-annotation-2.8.8.jar
- jackson-core-2.8.8.jar
- jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar
- jackson.datatype-joda-2.8.8.jar

## Mapper

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }  
}
```

## Error when calling the service

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS

## What I found

I already [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329418/error-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-write-durations-as-timestamps) that it may have a mismatch between different versions. All the jars come from maven repository and I took each times the dependencies needed.

## Question

What am I missing ? Is there a missing library ? Is there a wrong library's version ?

*Note: I am not using Maven*

## Update

I tried to update the *jackson-?.jars* inside `glassfish4.1/glassfish/modules` but now I cant even start the server because of a `requirement mismatch` with jackson versions

## Updates 2

Is there a way to use the jackson libraries that are inside my project instead of the one in Glassfish ? This seems to be the solution

Comment: Have you checked your local maven repository "~/.m2/repository" . I was facing the same issue twice 
Case 1:it turned out that some other version was being picked.

Comment: @PriyaJain As I said in the question (last line) - I am **not** using Maven

Comment: Ensure your Jackson dependencies are shipped with your WAR file. That is, under `/lib`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin They are shipped to `WEB-INF\lib` but I think that the problem comes from glassfish having `Jersey` which itself has a jackson dependency which is older than the one that I have

Comment: Using `<class-loader delegate="false" />` in the `glassfish-web.xml` deployment descriptor _could_ solve your issue.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Where is this file located ?

Comment: Under `WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the Jackson libraries that are inside my project instead of the one in Glassfish? This seems to be the solution.

See the following quote from the chapter 2 of the [GlassFish 4 Application Development Guide](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf):

> The Java Servlet specification recommends that a web module's class loader look in the local class loader before delegating to its parent. You can make this class loader follow the delegation inversion model in the Servlet specification by setting `delegate="false"` in the class-loader element of the `glassfish-web.xml` file. It is safe to do this only for a web module that does not interact with any other modules. [...]
>
> The default value is `delegate="true"`, which causes a web module's class loader to delegate in the same manner as the other class loaders. You must use `delegate="true"` for a web application that accesses EJB components or that acts as a web service client
>   or endpoint. [...]
>
> For a number of packages, including `java.*` and `javax.*`, symbol resolution is always delegated to the parent class loader regardless of the delegate setting. This prevents applications from overriding core Java runtime classes or changing the API versions of specifications that are part of the Java EE platform.

In the section B of the [GlassFish 4 Application Deployment Guide](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf) you'll find an example of the `glassfish-web.xml` deployment descriptor. Tailoring it to your issue, your `glassfish-web.xml` file would be like:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Then place it under `WEB-INF` of your web module.

Comment: I am now blocked with another problem linked to Joda but I think that your solution fixed my first error. Thanks !

Comment: @Weedoze If you ask another question, the Stack Overflow community may be able to help you :)

Comment: I know I know hehe I will first try to find a solution myself. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I finally asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652189/deserialize-datetime-joda-with-jackson)