# (De)Serialize DateTime (Joda) with Jackson

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, jodatime

I am building a REST webservice. Some classes have an attribute of type `DateTime` (JodaTime).

When sending this object to my client (Javascript), my object

```
private DateTime date;
```

is transformed to

```
{ date: { chronology: {}, millis: 1487289600000 } }
```

The problem is that I have an error when sending this object back to the server because I cannot instantiate `chronology`

I would like to have something like `{ date: 1487289600000}` - Any other format could work.

**Environment**

- jackson-annotations 2.8.8
- jackson-core 2.8.8
- jackson-databin 2.8.8
- jackson-datatype-joda 2.8.8
- joda-time 2.7

**My context resolver is**

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

What am I missing ? If I am not using `ObjectMapperContextResolver` I have the same result

## Update following @Cássio Mazzochi Molin's answer

I added `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider 2.8.8` , `jackson-jaxrs-base 2.8.8` and `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations 2.8.8`

My context resolver is now like this

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

And my application config

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        resources.add(AuthenticationFilter.class);
        resources.add(CORSFilter.class);
        resources.add(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
        resources.add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        resources.add(ServiceResource.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

My serviceResource

```
@Path("service")
public class ServiceResource {

    @Path("/forecast/stocks/{modelId}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Value> getStocks(@PathParam("modelId") String modelId, @QueryParam("startDate") String startDate, @QueryParam("endDate") String endDate) {
        try {
            DateTime datetimeStart = formatStringToDatetime(startDate);
            DateTime datetimeEnd = formatStringToDatetime(endDate);
            return logicClass.getStocks(modelId, datetimeStart, datetimeEnd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error calling /hydromax/forecast/stocks", e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

And the `Value` object

```
public class Value {

    private DateTime date;
    private Float value;

    public Value() {
    }

    //getter and setter

}
```

## Update

I have added the following code inside `ApplicationConfig`

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
    return props;
}
```

My `DateTime` is now transformed to

```
"date":{"dayOfMonth":16,"dayOfWeek":4,"era":1,"year":2017,"dayOfYear":47,"weekOfWeekyear":7,"secondOfMinute":0,"millisOfSecond":0,"weekyear":2017,"monthOfYear":2,"hourOfDay":10,"minuteOfHour":0,"yearOfEra":2017,"yearOfCentury":17,"centuryOfEra":20,"millisOfDay":36000000,"secondOfDay":36000,"minuteOfDay":600,"millis":1487235600000,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Europe/Paris"},"id":"Europe/Paris"},"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Europe/Paris"},"id":"Europe/Paris"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false}
```

And the first time I call the service after deployment, I have this error

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector

Comment: Have you registered your `ContextResolver`?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Yes `resources.add(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);`

Comment: For me, it works: `{"date":"2017-02-17T00:00:00.000Z"}`

Comment: @Hugo Do you use any other thing other than registering this class ? Do you use any annotation ? Any other configuration ?

Comment: @Hugo What do you mean by *it works for me* ? Did you copy paste my code ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I've made a simple test: create a class with the `DateTime` field, create the `ObjectMapper`, register the `JodaModule` and call `mapper.writeValueAsString`. I'm not using the context resolver.

Comment: @Hugo No problems. Then it is not really the same code as me. I am using this inside a Glassfish server for a Rest service. I am not calling `mapper.writeValueAsString`

Comment: I think you are missing the `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` dependency.

Comment: Have you tried annotating the `DateTime` field? Using this you can change the pattern, like: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")`

Comment: @Hugo I would like to find a general solution

Comment: What is your `ServiceResource` like? Show at least the signature of the method that handles the request.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Added

Comment: Except for `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` that should be `false`, everything looks fine to me. It may be something that goes beyond my knowledge...

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I just changed it to `false` and it still not works... I don't understand

Comment: As you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652189/deserialize-datetime-joda-with-jackson?noredirect=1#comment76292778_44652871), the `ObjectMapperContextResolver#getContext()` method is not getting invoked. Unfortunately I don't know the reason.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Thanks for your help. Hope I will find a solution.. It is really blocking my project..

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Are you sure that I am not supposed to use any annotation on my attribute ?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. But you can try something like `@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")`. You also could configure the format, if you want to, in the `JodaModule`, but `ObjectMapperContextResolver#getContext()` is not getting invoked...

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin It does nothing. Maybe because my full project is splitted in 4 projects ? (API, Logic, DAO, Model) ?

Comment: @Hugo I tried the annotation but it does not work

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I saw something very strange. While deploying my application on Glassfish I was refreshing the url to get my data and saw that one of the response (before the full deployment) was correctly serialized. Once the deployment was done, I refreshed the page and saw the json as posted in the question. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider) module in your application.

This module is the Jackson JSON provider for JAX-RS implementations, such as Jersey and RESTeasy.

A [`ContextResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) for [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) is only required if you need to customize the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) for the Jackson JSON provider. But the [`ContextResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) won't do anything if the Jackson provider is not registered.

---

Here's the dependency you need:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, add [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.8.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.8.8/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.8.jar) to the classpath.

Then register [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html) (using only Jackson annotations) or [`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.html) (using both Jackson and JAXB annotations), according to your needs.

Comment: I also added the dependencies of `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`. Thus I should only register `resources.add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);` instead of `resources.add(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);` ?

Comment: @Weedoze Register both. While the `JacksonJsonProvider` makes Jackson handle the JSON (de)serialization, the `ObjectMapperContextResolver` customizes the `ObjectMapper` for the Jackson provider.

Comment: Adding the module + dependencies and registering `JacksonJsonProvider` + `ObjectMapperContextResolver` is done. I still have the same result. Should I use any annotation on my attribute ?

Comment: @Weedoze Add a breakpoint to the `ObjectMapperContextResolver#getContext()` method and ensure that it's getting invoked.

Comment: The code inside the constructor of `ObjectMapperContextResolver` is invoked but not the method `getContext()`

Comment: @Weedoze The [method should be invoked](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/2.8/json/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.java#L194-L212) by `JacksonJsonProvider`.

Comment: Can it be an error because I have multiple `@Provider` ? An authenticationFilter and CorsFilter

Comment: @Weedoze You always can have filters along with the `JacksonJsonProvider`. It shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Okok - I have updated my question with the result of your answer

Comment: @Weedoze `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);` should be `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);`